# Set 'sharex' argument to 'axes1' and 'sharey' argument to 'axes1'

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

Define a numpy array 't' with expression 'np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)'.

Define another numpy array 's1' with expression 'np.sin(2np.pit)'

Define one more numpy array 's2' with expression 'np.sin(4np.pit)'.

Create a figure of size 8 inches in width, and 6 inches in height. Name it as fig.

Create an axes, using plt.subplot function. Name it as axes1. The subplot must point to first virtual grid created by 2 rows and 1 column. Set 'title' argument to 'Sin(2pix)'.

Draw a line plot of 't' and 's1' using 'plot' function on 'axes1`.

Create another axes, using plt.subplot function. Name it as axes2. The subplot must point to second virtual grid created by 2 rows and 1 column. Set 'title' argument to 'Sin(4pix)'. 
Set 'sharex' argument to 'axes1' and 'sharey' argument to 'axes1'.

Draw a line plot of 't' and 's2' using 'plot' function on 'axes2`.

Instruction for the 2nd and 3rd functions are provided in steps 3, 4 and 5 respectively. Please save your code and proceed to next step.

```
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
axes1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1, title='Sin(2pix)')
axes2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, title='Sin(4pix)')
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(4*np.pi*t)
axes1.plot(t, s1)
axes2.plot(t, s2)
```

How to set : Set 'sharex' argument to 'axes1' and 'sharey' argument to 'axes1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which axes to share while creating `axes2` as following. Rest of the code stays the same

```
axes2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, title='Sin(4pix)', sharex=axes1, sharey=axes1)
```

[image]

Comment: There are some posts on meta about answering homework question, which you might want to give a read.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I answered as the OP included a reproducible code. I agree completely that the way question is framed, it appears clearly as a homework. I will keep your words in mind the next time :)